# Customer can only have 01 orderOnSale subquery / CROSS APPLY in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cross-apply

I have created a dummy scenario that reflect many of the queries I have to write to check that  some data we are importing is correct.

The example would be when you have 3 tables

1. Store
2. Customer
3. CustomerOrder

A `Customer` can belong to many stores but can only 1 `OrderOnsale` can be bought x customer x store.

Cannot seem to get it right. Below is tables and noddy data + my attempt.

```
IF object_id(N'Store', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE Store
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Store]
(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [StoreName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Store] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

IF object_id(N'Customer', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE Customer
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [CustomerId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [StoreId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

IF object_id(N'CustomerOrder', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE CustomerOrder
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerOrder]
(
    [OrderId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [OrderName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OnSale] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([OrderId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

begin tran
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Store]([Id], [StoreName])
        SELECT 1, N'Harrods' UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, N'John Lewis'

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer]([CustomerId], [StoreId], [Name], [Surname])
        SELECT 1, 1, N'John', N'Smith' UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 2, N'Joe', N'Blogg'

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[CustomerOrder]([OrderId], [CustomerId], [OrderName], [OnSale])
        SELECT 1, 1, N'Toys', 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 1, N'Laptop', 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, 2, N'Toys', 0

        commit
```

My incomplete attempt:

```
SELECT
   HasCustomerBoughtMoreThanO1ItemOnSale =
      CASE WHEN Count(T2.TotalBoughtOnSale) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM 
   CustomerOrder co1 
INNER JOIN 
   customer c1 ON co1.CustomerId = c1.CustomerId
INNER JOIN 
   STORE S01 ON C1.StoreId = S01.Id
JOIN 
   (SELECT 
       CO2.CustomerId, S2.Id AS StoreId, 
       Count(CO2.OnSale) TotalBoughtOnSale
    FROM 
       CustomerOrder CO2
    INNER JOIN 
       customer c2 ON c2.CustomerId = CO2.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN 
       STORE S2 ON C2.StoreId = S2.Id
    WHERE 
       CO2.OnSale = 1       
    GROUP BY 
       CO2.CustomerId, S2.Id) AS t2 ON c1.CustomerId = T2.CustomerId 
                                    AND S01.Id = t2.StoreId
```

Comment: If "A Customer can belong to many stores" then your Customer table is wrong, because this is "customer belongs to particular StoreId store".

Comment: yes you are right but even if belong to 01 store I could I do it

Comment: It would greatly help us resolve your issue if you would create an SQLFiddle instead of posting all the code within the question.

Comment: I didnt know aboutn sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what your after is if a single customer has bought more then one `OnSale` item then this query will do the trick.

```
SELECT
CO.CustomerId, C.StoreId
FROM CustomerOrder CO
INNER JOIN Customer C ON CO.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
WHERE OnSale = 1
GROUP BY CO.CustomerId, C.StoreId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I should add that in this its given that a `Customer` can only shop in a single `Store` due to `StoreId` is a column in the `Customer` table.